# Deferred binding failed for 'com.mycompany.client.gin.ClientGinjector'

Tags: java, gwt, guice, gwt-platform, gwt-gin

I'm really having a hard time fixing the error below as I have properly added the the jars and the `<inherits ...>` in the `gwt.xml` file

0

```
5:27:22.011 [ERROR] [myapp] Failed to create an instance of 'com.mycompany.client.MainAppEntryPoint' via deferred binding

java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.mycompany.client.gin.ClientGinjector' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
    at com.mycompany.client.MainAppEntryPoint.&lt;init&gt;(MainAppEntryPoint.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/PresenterWidget, method: fireEvent signature: (Lcom/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent;)V) Incompatible argument to function
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1853)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:243)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:96)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:628)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor$1.visit(BindingProcessor.java:169)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor$1.visit(BindingProcessor.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingImpl.acceptTargetVisitor(UntargettedBindingImpl.java:42)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor.visit(BindingProcessor.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingProcessor.visit(BindingProcessor.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingImpl.acceptVisitor(BindingImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:172)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:103)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.validateModulesUsingGuice(BindingsProcessor.java:437)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.process(BindingsProcessor.java:241)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGeneratorImpl.generate(GinjectorGeneratorImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator.generate(GinjectorGenerator.java:47)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:647)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:78)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:268)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
    at com.mycompany.client.MainAppEntryPoint.&lt;init&gt;(MainAppEntryPoint.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:465)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:375)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here's my app main entry point class:

```
public class MainAppEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    private final ClientGinjector ginjector = GWT.create(ClientGinjector.class);

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        // Inject global styles
        GWT.<Resources>create(Resources.class).style().ensureInjected();

        // This is required for Gwt-Platform proxy's generator
        DelayedBindRegistry.bind(ginjector); // Line 10, reference from the stack trace above

        ginjector.getPlaceManager().revealCurrentPlace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your real problem seems to be on or around `Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/PresenterWidget, method: fireEvent signature: (Lcom/google/gwt/event/shared/GwtEvent;)V) Incompatible argument to function`. Can you show us PresenterWidget, or the class trying to inject it?

Comment: Its part of the GWT-platform framework: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/

Comment: Compile your code (you should get a better error message). Which version of GWTP are you using and post your ClientModule bindings and the code for your Presenter.

Comment: Man, I removed all the compiled "classes" and it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by doing a project cleanup with Eclipse